# connect to Postgresql with SSL

Tags: c#, postgresql, ssl

I am attempting to connect to a postgresql database which uses SSL via my c# application. But I'm unable to work out what the correct connection string would be. Is anyone able to help?

```
        NpgsqlConnection postgresConn;
        public PostgreManager()
        {
            openConnection();
        }

        private void openConnection()
        {
            postgresConn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=10.153.8.4;Port=5432;Database=au_wa_jpc;User Id=readonly;Password=myPass;");
            postgresConn.Open();

        }
```

Edit:

I have attempted to use `Ssl Mode=Require;` in the connection string, however it throws the following exception.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in Npgsql.dll

Additional information: TlsClientStream.ClientAlertException: CertificateUnknown: Server certificate was not accepted. Chain status: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.

. The specified hostname was not present in the certificate.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As described in the documentation [here](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html) and [here](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/security.html#encryption-ssltls), you'll have to use `SSL Mode=Require;Trust Server Certificate=true` in your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was reading [this article](https://pleasantpasswords.com/info/pleasant-password-server/b-server-configuration/4-changing-databases-for-pleasant-password-server/find-a-connection-string).

> PostgreSQL (SQL Authentication):
>
> Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=myDataBase;User
> ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
> SSL=TrueOrFalse;SslMode=RequireORDisable;
>
> Server=IP
> Address;Port=5432;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
> SSL=TrueOrFalse;SslMode=RequireORDisable;

The accepted answer did not work for me! It was rather this what worked:

> SSL=TrueOrFalse;SslMode=RequireORDisable;

The following connection string is working for me - not in a C# project though:

```
"postgresql://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@$<POSTGRES_HOST>/<POSTGRES_DATABASE>?ssl=true&sslmode=require"
```