# c# open connection to Postgres using sslrootcertificate in pem

Tags: c#, postgresql, x509certificate2

So I'm trying to open a connection to Postgres using C# and npgsql   Our system rules require sslmode to be VerifyFull.  There's an example in another language that I'm trying to copy - basically it sets the Root Certificate to a given file.

so I take the file and try to do the same thing - but it fails - and when I dig into the code - npgsql calls X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile.

- if I try to load up my certificate with

  X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem( File.ReadAllText( file )) it works fine.
- if I try to load up my certificate with

  X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile( file ) it doesn't work
- and that's because underneath, it calls CreateFromPem( text, text) where text is read from the file
- and my certificate doesn't have a key

so to summarise

- that certificate is working to that database with code in another language
- the ssl root certificate shouldn't need a key
- but it seems impossible for npgsqlconnection to load a certificate that doesn't have a key
- and I don't have a key

the error message is:

> "The key contents do not contain a PEM, the content is malformed, or the key does not match the certificate."
> Is there any way to fix this?

For more details - if I write the following test:

```cs
    var certificateFileName = @"C:\temp\blah.pem";
    //var decoded2 = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(certifcateFileName);
    var contents = File.ReadAllText(certificateFileName);
    var decoded = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem( contents, null);
    Assert.False( decoded.HasPrivateKey);
    var bytes = decoded.Export(X509ContentType.Cert);
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\temp\blah2.pem",  Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( new string(PemEncoding.Write("CERTIFICATE", bytes))));
    var decoded3 = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(@"C:\temp\blah2.pem");
```

throws an exception on the last line with any certificate I try.  Works fine if the certificate has a key

Comment: a link to the other language and your attempts including full error message would help

Comment: it's an internal ruby app - so it's hardly something I can link to - but the error message is: "The key contents do not contain a PEM, the content is malformed, or the key does not match the certificate." which is easily reproducible if I try to do a CreateFromPemFile for any .pem with only a certificate in it.

Comment: File.ReadAllText() is using ASCII Encoding while CreateFromPemFile() is not using ASCII.  ASCII encoding is removing non printable characters.

Comment: no we can't  reproduce your error as it basically works see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009311/connect-to-postgresql-with-ssl but it  looks more like the certificate you generate isn't ok. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.createfrompem?view=net-7.0 for more informaton

Comment: I have the same issue, could you find any solutions?